# Using play framework and scala how to display image path from database

Tags: scala, playframework

How to display image on view page in play framework and scala application,
from image path from database? I know how to display image from file on  statically , but i have no idea about how to do this. Please anyone have knew the answer please share here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put some methods on your controller just like this.
I have a controller `Profile` and I added a method `getImage(string id)` to return the photo of the person from db...

```
public class Profile extends Controller {
    public static void getImage(String id)
        {
            models.Person person = models.Person .findById(id);
            if(person.photo!=null)
            {
                ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(person.photo);
                renderBinary(input);
                return;
            }
            VirtualFile vf = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/public/images/no_photo.jpg");

            File f  = vf.getRealFile();
            renderBinary(f);
        }
    }
```

on your View,

you can use

```
<img src=@{Profile.getImage(person.id)}>
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: No, its from database... The person.photo is in byte format.. then loaded using ByteArrayInputStream(person.photo);
and then rendered as binary to display as image and can be used on your Views by using <img src=@{Profile.getImage(person.id)}>

Comment: This part is loading static image if no image from database...
VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/public/images/no_photo.jpg");

Comment: Was this with Play 1? VirtualFile doesn't seem to exist in Play 2's API.